# bootstrap: change modal backdrop opacity only for specific modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu with multiple modals. When I open one over another it turns backgrount into black, which is ugly.
I understand that I need change `filter: alpha(opacity=80);` in `.modal-backdrop.fade.in` in bootstrap.css. But I need to change it not for all modals, only for some of them. Here's the html code for first modal

```
    <div class="modal hide" id="mbusModal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>MBUS</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <form class="well form-inline">
                    <input type="button" class="btn" onclick="$('#dinMbusModal').modal('show'); $('#tabsMbusDin a:last').tab('show');" value="din">
                </form>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addPort('mbus',$('#mbusDev').val(),$('#mbusSpeed').val()); $('#mbusModal').modal('hide')">Применить</a>
        </div>
```

This modal needs to change his backdrop:

```
    <div class="modal hide" id="dinMbusModal" style="width: 500px; margin: -250px 0 0 -250px;">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h3>DIN</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addPort('din_mbus',,); $('#dinMbusModal').modal('hide')">Применить</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Little bit complicated by the fact that the backdrop is generated by the Modal plugin on the fly.  One possible way of doing it is adding a class to the body when you get a **show** event, then remove it on the **hidden**.

Something like:

### CSS

```
.modal-color-red .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #f00;
}
.modal-color-green .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #0f0;
}
.modal-color-blue .modal-backdrop {
  background-color: #00f;
}
```

### JS

```
$('.modal[data-color]').on('show hidden', function () {
  $('body').toggleClass('modal-color-'+ $(this).data('color'));
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="redModal" data-color="red">...</div>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="greenModal" data-color="green">...</div>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="blueModal" data-color="blue">...</div>
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/axhfF/)

Comment: just note that the event is now show.bs.modal and hidden.bs.modal e.g. $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal hidden.bs.modal')...

Answer (score 7):

**ONLY CSS / HTML**

JSFiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/szoys6d7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal hide fade modal2">...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal2.fade.in ~ .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
background-color: #f00; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the html markup for your modal

```
<div id="my-modal" class="modal hide fade">
    ....
</div>
```

Use this style in inside a style element in your html file

```
<style>
    #my-modal>.modal-backdrop.fade.in
    {
        opacity: .1; 
    }
</style>
```

and the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#my-modal").modal({
            show: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more your answer ?

Comment: This will not work... the class modal-backdrop is outside the modal div element... so the class will not work!!!

Answer (score 1):

For angular ui bootstrap:

Use `backdropClass`
when initialize:

```
$modal.open({templateUrl:'',
controller:'',
backdropClass:''
});
```

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.0/

Answer (score 0):

Took me forever, but I found a one-liner.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // remove greying background bootstrap modal effect
    $(".modal-backdrop ").attr('class', 'someClass');

});
```

Removing the class removed the modal. But renaming it keeps the functionality but gets rid of the background greying.

Answer (score -1):

Give your modals a separate classes

And all you need is:

.yourclass { background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); }